# Selenium: Element not clickable … Other Element Would Receive Click, click anyway

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The long and short of this is when I try to use

```
return this.driver.findElement(By.css("div[class*='img']")).click();
```

I get an error `Uncaught WebDriverError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (525, 889). Other element would receive the click:...`

How can I click anyway and let the "other element" receive the click? I'm using webdriverjs.

The reasoning behind this is basically the website I'm testing does some fancy react stuff which obscures the link somehow. Basically instead of attaching a link to an image, the entire image is covered with a transparent box that links you somewhere (don't ask me why). When you "click the image" you aren't *actually* clicking the image, but from a user point of view they are one and the same.

When I was using webdriverIO I could say

`browser.moveToObject("img");
 browser.leftClick();`

but we're moving away from that. I've also tried

```
this.driver.findElement(By.css("div[class*='img']"));
    return this.driver.actions().click().perform();
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything.

There have been a lot of questions about this error, but I haven't seen any that want you to click anyway.

Comment: I see you found an answer and that's what I would have suggested also. I'm actually surprised that `actions()` didn't work. That was going to be my second suggestion before I reread your question and saw you already tried it.

Comment: Yeah that one was weird in that it didn't trow an error, it just didn't seem to do anything at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a classic case of looking for an answer for hours, posting a question, and immediately finding an answer after, I found a work around:

```
var mylink = this.driver.findElement(By.css("div[class*='img']"));
return this.driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", mylink);
```